# How can I run a Selenium app with Chromedriver and Headless Chrome on Github Actions?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Context**

I've created a python app that uses selenium, chromedriver & chrome to automate actions on a website (roughly similar to the one here: https://yasoob.me/posts/web-automation-with-selenium/) . I'd like to run it on a schedule (e.g. every saturday at 9am) so, as the author suggested, I put it on Github Actions. I realize that for this to work I need to install Chromedriver & Chrome Headless as part of the Github Actions workflow.

My yml file looks like this:

```
name: Book

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 4 * * *"
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS: true

jobs:
  scrape-latest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      selenium:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2.0.0
        with:
          python-version: '3.7'
      - name: Install requirements
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      - name: Prepare Selenium
      # https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-chromedriver
        uses: nanasess/setup-chromedriver@master
       

      - name: Run Booker
        run: python app.py
```

**Issue**

I get the following error message:

```
Run python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 19, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.15/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.15/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.15/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.15/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.15/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried different versions of this, where I put chromedrive as a binary in the requirements.txt, or try to install it through the app.py file, but it seems like putting it in the workflow file is the most reasonable place to start.

**My Ask**

1. Conceptually: I've never really done anything like this before so I'm having a hard time understanding the logic of what I'm doing - I guess Github Actions runs an Ubuntu server, where each time I run the action, I need to install Chrome (in headless mode) and Chromedriver, so that I can then run the automation that's in app.py. Is that more or less correct?
2. Tactically: What am I doing wrong in the code above?

Thank you!